# Date Range in days....C#

Tags: c#, datetime, range, timespan

I have a query that is calling an Oracle DB from C#.  I want to write the query to get data that is, at most, 5 years old.

I currently have a hard coded value for `public const int FIVE_YEARS_IN_DAYS = 1825;`

But, this isn't correct because of leap years.  Is there a function that will give me the correct number of days in the preceeding 5 years?

Comment: Why not use 365.25 days per year?

Comment: @PostMan - that is not always accurate. We don't have leap years every 4 years. Dealing with time is one area in programming where it's much better to use a hardened, tested solution. It's easy to get bitten.

Comment: @All....thanks for the input.  Very helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;    
now.AddYears(-5).Subtract( now ).Days
```

Comment: To catch the perhaps unlikely event of this calculation being performed around midnight, you might consider capturing DateTime.Now first and then performing the calculation using the captured value.

Comment: I was hoping to just put @Matt Greer on the right path, but good point.

Comment: I would think that `DateTime.Today` would be a better choice than `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: `DateTime.Today` would still have the midnight boundary issue that DateTime.Now has.

Answer (score 4):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan fiveYears = now.Subtract(now.AddYears(-5));
int numberOfDaysInLastFiveYears = fiveYears.Days;
```

This will correctly account for leap years. Doing this right now yields 1,826 days.

Comment: Same comment as I made to @Babak Naffas answer.  Probably safer to capture DateTime.Now and used the captured value to perform the calculation.

Comment: Yeah, that is correct. Capturing `DateTime.Now` in general is good practice.